# Trying to use Launcher.LaunchUriAsync in a Share Target app win Win 8

Tags: c#, share, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I’m building an app that acts as a share target for URI’s; it takes the URI then URL for invokes the browser to our web site for sharing.  I have the code working using the sharing target sample, however Launcher.LaunchUriAsync is always failing when I’m outside the debugger.  It doesn’t throw though so I’m having a hard time figuring out what the error might be; maybe some security context.

Any ideas?  The code itself is pretty short; I get success = false running directly from the shell and invoking via Win-C/Share.  I’ve made sure the manifest has all three networking declarations set.  Other thoughts?

```
if (this.shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Uri))
{
    Uri uri = await this.shareOperation.Data.GetUriAsync();
    if (uri != null)
    {
        Uri tempUri;
        Uri.TryCreate("http://www.mysite.com/#/search?v=results&bk=1.0&q="+uri.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute, out tempUri);
        bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(tempUri);
        if (success) {
            contentValue.Text += "Success invoking browser" + ":URL="+tempUri.ToString()+ Environment.NewLine;
        } else {
            contentValue.Text += "Fail invoking browser" + ":URL=" + tempUri.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This runs fine under debugger?  or is it that you haven't figured out how to attach debugger to a share target?  the latter problem I can help with...

Answer (score 1):

A sharing target shouldn't be launching another application. Share targets are meant to be hosted inside the sharing pane, and should provide a quick, in-context way for the user to share content with your app or service.

In your case, perhaps you should host a WebView and navigate that to your service's URL?

Answer (score 0):

There are several conditions that needs to be met in order to successfully call LaunchUriAsync.

As seen [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701480.aspx) you need to ensure the following:

1. The calling app must be visible to the user when the API is invoked.
2. Unless you are calling this API from a Classic Windows application, this API must be called from within an ASTA thread (also known as a UI thread).
3. You must specify the privateNetworkClientServer capability in the manifest in order to launch intranet URIs, for example a file:/// URI pointing to a network location.
4. You cannot use this method to launch a URI in the local zone. For example, apps cannot use the file:/// protocol to access files on the local computer. Instead, you must use the Storage APIs to access files.

I guess that one of the first two conditions is why your code fails. (At least that was my problem)